# How can I install Quicktime player to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, installation, video, windows-10, quicktime

I would like to play a movie in the web and a webpage ask me, download Quicktime plugin.  I opened up this web page and I tryed download and install [Quicktime](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/thankyou/index.html)

But when I tried install I get this alert messange:

[image]

I also tried checked compatibility mode to windows 7, but the situation is same, I can't install Quicktime.
What can I do now?

Comment: Have you referred to the correct suitable bit compatibility? Eg. a 32bit version, which should work on both Intel x86 and amd64 systems. If you got a 64bit version and have a x86 windows 7 then it won't be compatible.

Comment: [How to Install QuickTime on Windows 10](http://tommynation.com/install-quicktime-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On different [forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/690c031d-2271-44f2-8349-375055334b9d/windows-10-and-apple-quicktime?forum=WinPreview2014General), it's been told that older versions of QuickTime (previous to 7.7.7) might work on W10. Try downloading 7.7.6 for Windows [here](https://support.apple.com/downloads/quicktime).

UPDATE. I think it's about some extra validations on the installer. I happen to have W10 Pro x64 but I upgraded from W7 and it says a newer version is installed. That means, the program itself runs but the installer on recent versions have some extra logic that prevents it from running on untested environments.

[image]

Also, check that you can manually run QuickTime exe (C:\Program Files(x32)\QuickTime\QuickTimePlayer.exe).

If your browser does not show content, it might be related to Chrome not accepting old x32 plugins (or NPAPI plugins at all) from v42 on as stated [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en).

Comment: This is realy strange.
You're right, the program is instaled, but the page is still ask me download this plugin.

Comment: The QuickTime plugin might require you to restart your browser.

Comment: If you check on C:\Program Files(x32)\QuickTime, can you run QuickTimePlayer.exe? Any odd message while running the installer? Which browser are you trying to use?

Comment: Latest chrome, I installed to D:// becouse I not have space on C, but I can opened it from Instaled directroy.
The whole thing becouse of Airdroid...

Comment: It might be related to Chrome not accepting old x32 plugins (or NPAPI plugins at all) from v42 on. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en

Comment: Haha You're right I enabled this API in here:
chrome://flags/#enable-npapi
Unlucky statemant:
"This video format unsupported "
Now my right eye blink faster then left...

Comment: Hahaha, sorry. Seems like an unlucky sequence of problems. QT should handle that without hassle, try installing VLC and/or rebooting.

Comment: Ugh, maybe you can use that airdroid on desktop version instead of chrome so it can work. Also, I added relevant comments to the main answer. Sorry I couldn't help any further. Maybe if you address the problem with Airdroid itself in a new question...

Answer (score 1):

### I was able to install Quicktime Player 7.7.8 on Windows 10.

Here is how you can do it:

---

1. Downloaded [QuickTime](http://www.apple.com/uk/quicktime/download/).
2. Download [Super Orca](http://www.pantaray.com/msi_super_orca.html).
3. Extract the `QuickTimeInstaller.exe` (using any zip file extractor such as WinRAR).
4. Open Super Orca and open the QuickTime.msi which you extracted in step 3
5. On the leftside click on "LaunchCondition"
6. Then you will see the conditions for installation on the right side
7. Doubleclick on "(VersionNT>501) AND (VersionNT<=603)" and change it to "(VersionNT>501) AND (VersionNT<=604)" and click OK
8. The doubleclick on "BUSEROSVERSION AND (BUSEROSVERSION<10)" and change it to "BUSEROSVERSION AND (BUSEROSVERSION<=10)" and click OK.
9. In Super Orca click then on "Tools" and choose "Install MSI (/i)"
10. Go through the installation wizard.